# Help finding ALL the critical points of this function

Tags: derivatives

$$f(x)=x^{2/3}(5-x)$$
So I derived the function and came up with:
$$f'(x)=\frac{10-5x}{3x^{1/3}}$$
I then made it equal to 0:
$$0=\frac{10-5x}{3x^{1/3}}$$
multiply both sides by the denominator and got:
$$0=10-5x$$
$$-10=-5x$$
$$x=2$$
Then I sub it into f(x) to get the y value.
I feel like there are more critical points though. If so then how do i find them? i feel like I should do more with the $3x^{1/3}$ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct and you can easely see that $x=2$ is a maximum. But note also that the derivative is not defined for $x=0$ and we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)= \infty$.

Comment: oh so x=0 is also a critical point as well as x=2?

Comment: Yes, by classical definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

You found all critical points. The expression $$\frac{10-5x}{3x^{\frac13}}$$

is only equal to $0$ if $x=2$.

To be extra sure, you can plot the function in [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E%282%2F3%29%20*%20%285-x%29)